How to write test cases in selenium java for automatic dropdown, constructed in div tag
I am struggling to get a hold of a dynamic drop down to run unit test . Can some suggest how to get hold of auto complete drop down. The moment I try to click on drop down to inspect , the drop down disappears. Therefore, i am unable to iterate over the options of drop-down . The URL is https://www.flydubai.com/en-gb/. my code is d.get("https://www.flydubai.com/en-gb/");
d.manage().window().maximize();
d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // Accept cookies
    WebElement cookiesDialog = d.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'osano-cm-dialog')]"));
    WebElement acceptButton = cookiesDialog.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[contains(@class, 'osano-cm-accept-all')]"));
    acceptButton.click();

    // Select one-way option
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d, 10);
    WebElement oneWay = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@class=\"MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body1 jss1  css-1l0ew3p\"]")));
    oneWay.click();

    // Interact with the input field to trigger dropdown
    WebElement fromInput = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("from-airportsList")));
    fromInput.click();
    fromInput.sendKeys("Glasgow");

    // Wait for suggestions to appear
    WebDriverWait waitForSuggestions = new WebDriverWait(d, 10);

    // Try to locate the dropdown suggestions based on the parent structure
    List<WebElement> suggestions = waitForSuggestions.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
            By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'MuiAutocomplete-root')]//div[contains(@role, 'option')]")
    ));

    // If suggestions are not found, try a more general approach
    if (suggestions.isEmpty()) {
        suggestions = waitForSuggestions.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
                By.xpath("//div[@role='listbox']//div[@role='option']")
        ));
    }

    // Iterate through suggestions and select "Glasgow"
    boolean suggestionFound = false;
    for (WebElement suggestion : suggestions) {
        String suggestionText = suggestion.getText();
        System.out.println("Suggestion: " + suggestionText);

        if (suggestionText.contains("Glasgow")) {
            suggestionFound = true;
            suggestion.click();
            break;
        }
    }

    // Assert that the suggestion was found
    Assert.assertTrue("Suggestion 'Glasgow' was not found in the dropdown.", suggestionFound);

i am trying to get hold of dropdown and iterate over to get all possible options i get for sendKeys("Gla")

I tried to keep the dropdown source code in the Firefox developer tools. you may try these steps in Firefox:

Open the 'flydubai' page and open developer tools.
In the 'Debugger' tab of the developer tools. Add an event listener breakpoints for 'Keyboard' -> 'keyup'
Switch to your 'flydubai' page. input a char 'a' in the 'From' input.
Then you will find the page stopped when you 'keyup' the 'a'.

You can find the dropdown source codes in the 'Inspector' tab of Firefox developer tools. They are added to the last section of ''

Here are the code snippets of your dropdown.


<div role="presentation" class="MuiAutocomplete-popper css-1ozefeb" style="max-width: 370px; max-height: 340px; min-width: 370px; margin: 36px 0px 0px; border-radius: 11px; z-index: 1; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 6px 24px 0px; position: absolute; transform: translate3d(186px, 583px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;" x-placement="bottom-start">
   <div class="MuiPaper-root MuiPaper-elevation MuiPaper-rounded MuiPaper-elevation1 MuiAutocomplete-paper css-18h49fy">
      <ul dir="ltr" style="width: 100%; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; border-top-left-radius: 11px; border-top-right-radius: 11px;" class="myCustomList myCustomListMargin css-pwdjp1" role="listbox" id="from-airportsList-listbox" aria-labelledby="from-airportsList-label">
         <div dir="ltr" class="AirportListAutoComplete_currentLocation__Q3CmA">
            Use current location
            <div class="AirportListAutoComplete_currentIconContainer__ggEgL"><img alt="Current location" loading="lazy" width="22" height="22" decoding="async" data-nimg="1" style="color: transparent;" src="/v2/_next/static/media/gps-location.bb8088a1.svg"></div>
         </div>
         <li>
            <ul class="css-y8aj3r">
               <li class="MuiAutocomplete-option MuiBox-root css-0" style="padding: 0px; font-family: inherit;" tabindex="-1" role="option" id="from-airportsList-option-0" data-option-index="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
                  <div style="width: 100%;">
                     <div style="background-color: rgb(0, 156, 222);" class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportListItem__mJ_Xo">
                        <div class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportListLeft__UBwAG"><span class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportCountry__IUvL7" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Abha, Saudi Arabia</span><span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportTitle__GjVw2">Abha Airport</span></div>
                        <div class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportListRight__VsiaX"><span class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportCode__JyqCV">AHB</span></div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="AirportListAutoComplete_dividerContainerDesktop__UagAW">
                        <div class="AirportListAutoComplete_desktopDivider__hbA9Z"></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </li>
               <li class="MuiAutocomplete-option MuiBox-root css-0" style="padding: 0px; font-family: inherit;" tabindex="-1" role="option" id="from-airportsList-option-1" data-option-index="1" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
                  <div style="width: 100%;">
                     <div class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportListItem__mJ_Xo">
                        <div class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportListLeft__UBwAG"><span class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportCountry__IUvL7">Abidjan, Ivory Coast</span><span class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportTitle__GjVw2">Felix Houphouet-Boigny International Airport</span></div>
                        <div class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportListRight__VsiaX"><span class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportCode__JyqCV">ABJ</span></div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="AirportListAutoComplete_dividerContainerDesktop__UagAW">
                        <div class="AirportListAutoComplete_desktopDivider__hbA9Z"></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
            <div class="css-z67u16">K</div>
            <ul class="css-y8aj3r">
               <li class="MuiAutocomplete-option MuiBox-root css-0" style="padding: 0px; font-family: inherit;" tabindex="-1" role="option" id="from-airportsList-option-148" data-option-index="148" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
                  <div style="width: 100%;">
                     <div class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportListItem__mJ_Xo">
                        <div class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportListLeft__UBwAG"><span class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportCountry__IUvL7">Kabul, Afghanistan</span><span class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportTitle__GjVw2">Kabul Airport</span></div>
                        <div class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportListRight__VsiaX"><span class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportCode__JyqCV">KBL</span></div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="AirportListAutoComplete_dividerContainerDesktop__UagAW">
                        <div class="AirportListAutoComplete_desktopDivider__hbA9Z"></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </li>
               <li class="MuiAutocomplete-option MuiBox-root css-0" style="padding: 0px; font-family: inherit;" tabindex="-1" role="option" id="from-airportsList-option-149" data-option-index="149" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
                  <div style="width: 100%;">
                     <div class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportListItem__mJ_Xo">
                        <div class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportListLeft__UBwAG"><span class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportCountry__IUvL7">Kaohsiung, Taiwan</span><span class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportTitle__GjVw2">Kaohsiung International Airport</span></div>
                        <div class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportListRight__VsiaX"><span class="AirportListAutoComplete_airportCode__JyqCV">KHH</span></div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="AirportListAutoComplete_dividerContainerDesktop__UagAW">
                        <div class="AirportListAutoComplete_desktopDivider__hbA9Z"></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </li>  
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>



